# Mask Image to Video Frame similar as MV Master

Tags: java, android, video, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am new to this video processing concept, i tried to use the video sample downloaded from the [link](http://ak-mv.inscoming.com/zif/2019/01/04/14/027ac097fb788c698ad5e7cb3c92fd69.zip) of MV Master. And used ffmpeg to mask images in the video same as MV Master does in their app. I used VideoKit([link](https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android)) to do that. Can any one help me out with this.

Comment: @Zoe Ok thanks for the correction

Comment: have you got the solutionn?

Comment: @VineshChauhan not yet

Comment: i am doing this by ffmpeg

Comment: @VineshChauhan I already tried with ffmpeg but the processing time is more. i also implemented few commands [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55036675/4962397)

Comment: Have you got Solution?